# Compare-Objectにおける、ソート順の差異による出力結果の違いについて

Tags: powershell

Compare-Objectにおける、ソート順の差異による出力結果の違いについての質問です。

#### 前提事項

比較元と比較先でソート順を変えてdiffを取った場合、バイナリによる比較とハッシュ値による比較では結果が異なります。
具体的に申し上げますと、下記ディレクトリ構成の「file1.txt」を異なる内容にした場合、
バイナリ比較では、比較元の「修正前.xlsx」と比較先の「file1.txt」で差分を出力します。（ディレクトリの違いによるアンマッチを出力する。）
ハッシュ値の比較では、比較元の「file1.txt」と比較先の「file1.txt」で差分を出力します。（同ディレクトリ配下のアンマッチを出力する。）

#### 質問事項

なぜハッシュ値による比較では、比較元と比較先でソート順が違うのに同ディレクトリの差分のみを出力できるのか？
バイナリ比較とハッシュ値比較での挙動の違いについて説明可能な方がいましたら、ご教示頂けますでしょうか。

#### コード

```
#比較元と比較先でソート順を別にしている。
$master = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath [比較元ディレクトリ] -Recurse -File | Sort-Object{$_.LastWriteTime}
$work = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath [比較先ディレクトリ] -Recurse -File | Sort-Object{$_.FullName}

#バイナリ比較
@(Compare-Object (Get-Content -Encoding Byte $master.FullName) (Get-Content -Encoding Byte $work.FullName) -PassThru)

#ハッシュ値比較
@(Compare-Object -Property Hash (Get-FileHash $master.FullName) (Get-FileHash $work.FullName) -PassThru)
```

#### ディレクトリ構成(比較元と比較先で同一)

```
dir1
 └─dir2
     └─dir3
         ├─PG1
         │      file1.txt
         │      file2.txt
         │      file3.txt
         │      
         └─PG2
                 修正前.xlsx
```

Comment: いまいち何を尋ねたいのかよくわかりませんでした。２つの結果が一致しないことを指摘しているのはわかります。一方は期待しない結果なのだとは思いますが、他方は期待する結果なのかそちらも期待しない結果なのか、それはどちらなのか、読み取れませんでした。`Compare-Object`の比較結果を尋ねているように読めましたが、問題はそこなのでしょうか？ `Get-Content`や`Get-FileHash`が既に期待しない結果だったりするなら比較以前の問題です。もっというと`$master.FullName`は期待する結果ですか？